# Namespaces used in multiple C++ source files

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern

I have a DLL project with a `.h` file that defines a class and related variables all in a namespace.  This is Windows XP using VS 2008.  Though it's obvious, this is a gstreamer program :-)

I want the variable `receiverList` in the namespace `IPC_RECEIVER`, but I want to look at it outside that namespace in, for example, the corresponding `IPC_SENDER` namespace.

```
// IPC-Receiver..h

#ifndef IPCRECEIVER_H_
   #define IPCRECEIVER_H_

   namespace IPC_RECEIVER
   {  
   ....  class declaration.
   }
   typedef std::list<IPC_RECEIVER::GstReceiver*>             ReceiverList_t;
   typedef std::list<IPC_RECEIVER::GstReceiver*>::iterator   ReceiverListIter_t;

#endif /* IPCRECEIVER_H_ */
```

Then a cpp file  where the variable g_receiverList is declared in the IPC_RECEIVE namespace but not in any class.

```
// IPC-ReceeiverAPIs.cpp
#include "IPC-Receiver.h"

namespace IPC_RECEIVER
{
   ReceiverList_t    g_receiverList;    // list to track receivers
   ...
}
```

And finally a third file

```
// IPC-Receiver.cpp

#include "IPC-Receiver.h"

extern ReceiverList_t  g_receiverList;  

namespace IPC_RECEIVER
{
   GstReceiver::GstReceiver()
   {
      g_receiverList.push_back( this );
   }
}
```

When I compile this I get this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
   "class std::list<class IPC_RECEIVER::GstReceiver *,
   class std::allocator<class IPC_RECEIVER::GstReceiver *> > g_receiverList" 
   (?g_receiverList@@3V?$list@PAVGstReceiver@IPC_RECEIVER@
   @V?$allocator@PAVGstReceiver@IPC_RECEIVER@@@std@@@std@@A)
   IPC-Receiver.obj
```

I have tried various combinations of adding the namespace name in the extern and in the constructor.

With

```
IPC_RECEIVER::g_receiverList.push_back( this );
```

I get:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'g_receiverList' : is not a member of 
'IPC_RECEIVER'  x:\Projects\IPC-dll\IPC-dll\IPC-Receiver.cpp    54  IPC-dll
```

And with

```
extern ReceiverList_t  IPC_RECEIVER::g_receiverList;
```

I get two errors:

```
Error   2   error C2039: 'g_receiverList' : is not a member of 'IPC_RECEIVER'   x:\Projects\IPC-dll\IPC-dll\IPC-Receiver.cpp    22    
Error   2   error C2039: 'g_receiverList' : is not a member of 'IPC_RECEIVER'   x:\Projects\IPC-dll\IPC-dll\IPC-Receiver.cpp    55
```

where 22 and 54 are the lines where `g_receiverList` is used.

using `::` instead of `IPC_RECEIVER::` also does not work.

So, how do I make this work: declare a variable in a namespace in one file and use it in another?

Is this a link order problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the extern in the namespace

```
namespace IPC_RECEIVER
{
   extern ReceiverList_t    g_receiverList;
}
```

And then use it with a qualified name from code that is not within the IPC_RECEIVER namespace.

e.g.

```
void main() {
   IPC_RECEIVER::g_receiverList.push_back(...);
}
```

In you example you are in the IPC_RECEIVER namespace so you wouldn't need the `IPC_RECEIVER::` bit.

Comment: Bingo!  Worked immediately.